# Pagination with PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have been trying to resolve a paging problem and I do not understand the following code.

```
                $lstart = ($page * 6) -6;
                $lend = ($page * 6)-1;
                $limit = $lstart.','.$lend;
```

The results I get are mixed.  I should get six articles per page, but it is inconsistent.  The code is incorporated in a script I inherited from someone else and I am trying to fix it.  Can someone explain this code to me?   In the query, LIMIT=$limit.

Comment: If that's `LIMIT start, number`, it's not a `start/stop` context. It's *start with record `35`, give me the next `30`*. So it doesn't look right from that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be...

```
$lstart = ($page * 6) -6; // quite frankly, it's clearer to write...
       // ($page - 1) * 6
$limit = $lstart.',6';
```

The second clause in limit declares how many items. Not up to a certain point.

---

From mysql docs: (copy/paste)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

So, 1,10 would be rows 2-11
Thus, to get row 1, you need to set the offset to zero: 0,10 which would give you rows 1-10.

You can also check out further tutorials on LIMIT here: http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

---

Code with explanation.

```
$rows_per_page = 6; // you're trying to get 6 rows for every "page".

// On page 1, you'd want rows 0-5 (6 rows inclusively)
// On page 2, you'd want rows 6-111 (again, 6 rows inclusively)
// and so forth.
// So when $page == 1, you want to start at 0, on page 2, start at 6....
// To express this pattern mathematically, we write:
$start = ($page - 1) * 6

// mysql takes offset and number as it's two variables in the LIMIT clause, 
// in that order, when two are provided.
// So we write:
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT $start, $rows_per_page;";

// So, at page 1, you get
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 6;"; // if we were to substitute the variables.
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT 6, 6;"; // at page 2
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT 12, 6;"; // at page 3
```

Comment: Very similar to Jonathan's response.  The only difference is the +1 in his code.  I tried yours as well and got the same results.  All of the articles on one page.

Comment: @Learner The `+1` in Johanathan's answer of `$lstart = ($page - 1) * 6 + 1;` is actually wrong unless you want to start from second record only. The offset value starts from zero. You can confirm this via mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html as well as testing. If you are getting ALL results, it would mean that you have error elsewhere and not in the specific "0,6" string. Edit: I've edited my answer with the excerpt from mysql docs to show how offset works.

Comment: I changed my query to read LIMIT 5,10 and I used your code above Slstart=($page-1) *6 and Slimit = $lstart. ,6'; I got 5 records and the seond page I got an sql syntax error.  Johnathan did send me a correction to his code but it did not help.

Comment: When I change LIMIT=$limit to LIMIT 5,10  Why would I need $limit =$lstart.',6':

Comment: @Learner `... LIMIT=5` is equivalent to `... LIMIT=0,5`. Additionally, if you're getting synatx error or weird behaviors, the problem is with the rest of the code. Not the limit clause.

Comment: So if I say LIMIT=0,120 I should get 120 records (0 being 1 so to speak).  Then the problem is breaking the results down into pages.  Johathan pointed out than in my original coding, I would get 5 records on the first page, 11 records on the second and using his logic I can expect to see 17 records on the next page added.  That is using LIMIT=$limit in the query and defining $limit as I did in the original code.

Comment: I took another look at your solution  $lstart = ($page-1)*6 and $limit = $lstart.',6'; AND GLORY BE this worked!!

Comment: I still get a sql error on my local server, but then that is another problem.  It works on the remote server and for right now that is all that counts.  Thanks again.

Comment: Grumpy, this code does work but can you explain the code in a little bit more detail.

Comment: @Learner I understand you're learning but, even more detail is rather... very basic you should easily cover by yourself. Any case, I've added it for you this time. But should learn to familiarize yourself with various manuals.